# LibreOffice No other formats available on save as

Tags: libreoffice, configuration

I was trying to save a file as an RTF format in Ubuntu LibreOffice. . .  I go down to format, and there are *no* options at all. . .

How can I fix this?  Also, why is this like this on my vanilla Gnome LibreOffice?

-K

Comment: Where is Format in the File > Save as dialog? There is `Filter` with a dropdown of choices.

Comment: May be different in different versions I have [this](https://imgur.com/a/5qpWZtq).

Comment: [@kakunka](https://askubuntu.com/users/856934/kakunka) What is LibreOffice. . . is it Writer or not.

Answer (score 0):

You should see something similar to this:

[image: Filter]

Comment: May be different versions have different styles. I have [this](https://imgur.com/a/5qpWZtq)

Comment: And what happens when you click on the arrow to the right of "All formats"?

Comment: [Like this.](https://imgur.com/a/prIvSER)

Comment: So you see RTF as well. I wonder what problem the person who asked the question has?

Comment: I think he is not saving the file from LibreOffice Writer. May be Calc, Draw or Impress. Anyway he is not responding so...

Comment: Actually, the way it looks is the posted picture from Hobbyist.  After repeated noodling I was able to get the formats to appear, however the list appears blank when I first click on it. . .  Only by going down into the "empty" list, and clicking the down arrow do actual items begin appearing. . .  It is indeed "writer". . . I've used it plenty in Windows, but it's behavior is quite different in Ubuntu. . .